# Unable to import CSV file data to mysql table

Tags: python, mysql, database

I am using the code below-

```
import mysql.connector
import csv

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host='xxxxx', user='xxxx', passwd='xxxxxx')

cursor = mydb.cursor()
cursor.execute("SHOW DATABASES")
l = cursor.fetchall()

cursor.execute("USE DB ")

with open('details.csv','rt')as f:
    csv_data = csv.reader(f)

   for row in csv_data:
       cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO student (id,name,age,course) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)',row)
cursor.close()
mydb.commit()
mydb.close()
```

I am getting the following error-
"ProgrammingError: Not all parameters were used in the SQL statement"
python 3.x,windows7,Mysql 2012 version.

Comment: there is one or more then less 4 column in your csv..  So Could you please check again...

Comment: there are only four columns in my CSV file with the same names

Answer (score 0):

In this case, the main problem is the string format. I did't know what object is `row`, in your error it is a list, so using each element will solve the issue.

```
for row in csv_data:
       cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO student (id,name,age,course) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s)',
row[0], row[1], row[2], row[3])
```

Comment: 'DB' is the name of the database in mysql. I am using Insert statement

Comment: AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'split'. This is the error I am getting when I tried.

Comment: I tried that it is showing the following error - "ProgrammingError: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '[0],row[1],row[2],row[3],row[4],row[5],row[6],row[7],row[8],row[9],row[10],row[1' at line 1"

Answer (score 0):

```
for row in csv_data:
    listval = []
    for col in row:
        listval.append(col)

    cursor.execute ('INSERT INTO student (id,name,age,course) VALUES (%s,%s,%s,%s) ', listval)
```

This will work :))

Comment: its showing the same error after using db parameter.